# AfterTargets failures don't fail msbuild run

Tags: msbuild

In my solution, some project have tasks that need to run at the end, such as copy files to various places.  We implement that with `AfterTargets="Build"`:

```
<Target Name="CopyStuff" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..." DestinationFolder="..." />
</Target>
```

If works. However, when building the solution (not the individual project!), if the copy fails, we get a red build warning, but msbuild (and therefore TFS build) succeeds:

```
> msbuild /t:clean;build my.sln
(...)
(in red...) error MSB3021: Unable to copy file (...)

> echo %errorlevel%
0     <<<<<<< This means succeeded
```

To my understanding, that's because msbuild thinks that as long as the major "Build" target passed, everything passed too.

Our workaround - Change target to `BeforeTargets="AfterBuild"`, which puts my target inside the Build target. However, this requires knowledge of the content of "Build" target, and may not work for other project types.

Question:

1. Is there a way to get `AfterTargets="Build"` failures to fail solution builds?
2. If not, is there a way to automatically validates that people didn't add `AfterTargets="Build"` into their projects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an <Error /> after the <Copy /> task to throw an error if the contents of the Source and Destination are not the same?